# The fastest way to toggle VPN connection for Windows 7 or later?

Tags: windows, vpn

When I connect to my company VPN, I cannot browse internet normally i.e. even open google.com

So I need to turn on and off that VPN connection very often and currently I have to go to the connection page and toggle it.

What is the fastest way to do this? I hope to have a toggle button or shortcut so that I can toggle VPN connection - similar feature for using proxy server is [IE Proxy Toggle](http://skwire.dcmembers.com/fp/?page=ie-proxy-toggle)

Comment: You could also just set your VPN to split routing. Then everything work related still goes via the VPN, but the other destinations (read: Internet) still is locally routed and accessible.

Comment: How to split routing for the VPN @Hennes?

Comment: That depends on the VPN client you use (which is currently not specified in the question). Some some it is as simple as placing a checkmark. For some client it is not possible or explicitly blocked. The last is often done on corporate laptops where they want to enforce access via corporate virus scanners or want to completely block the unsafe Internet.  Depending on the firm this might be valid (e.g. I would not allow laptops with medical information on them to reach the Internet).  If it is your own laptop then please add the used VPN software to your post.